# mysql import .sql dump using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, import, phpmyadmin, quote

In PHPMyAdmin, I am trying to import a sqldump file which seems created using --quote-names. I get an error for the sql commands which have double quoted table names and fields names. How can I import the file im PHPMyAdmin?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "articles" (
  "ar_id" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  "ar_code" varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  "ar_group" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "ar_description" varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  "ar_text" longtext NOT NULL,
  "ar_explanation" text NOT NULL,
  "ar_date" varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  "ar_last_update" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "ar_creation_date" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  "ar_update_user" varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY ("ar_id")
) AUTO_INCREMENT=317 ;
```

when I remove double qutes, the script working fine. The size of the file is about 600 MB

Answer (score 0):

If PHPMyAdmin doesn't support it, restore to a local mySQL database and dump an importable version from there.

Set the SQL mode to `ANSI` : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes

There is an option to change the SQL mode on the phpMyAdmin import page.

Comment: My problem is that it cannot be imported. I tried a lot to import in using "MySQL source c:\dump.sql". but no success :(

Comment: `--quote-names` is not supposed to generate double quotes, how was the dump performed?

Comment: I don't know. In my project, I need to import the file into MySQL. The file is created years ago using PHPMyAdmin by somebody who I don't know them. This is the header of the file and the first sql statement that cuses the error:

Comment: Looks like you will have to edit the file manually and fix the syntax. Post the line which is giving you trouble.

Comment: Edit your post and add it there, remove the comments